# Pandas 0.17.1 dataframe manipulation refering a column and writen to csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi friends I am new to programming and I am having a difficult time accessing this dataframe that I read from a html
is just i want to print a specific column and because they are unnamed...I've tryed everything to access them and it throw's me some errors....this what I've tried so far to print them out:

```
print [data{'Unnamed: 0'}]

[           Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2   Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4  \
0            Pinnacle         NaN        NaN          NaN        NaN   
1    10/25 02:06:10pm         NaN       #101        Miami        NaN   
2    10/25 02:06:10pm         NaN       #102  New England        NaN   
3    10/25 04:40:03pm         NaN       #101        Miami        NaN   
4    10/25 04:40:04pm         NaN       #102  New England      8½-05   
5    10/25 04:40:12pm         NaN       #101        Miami        NaN   
6    10/25 04:40:12pm         NaN       #102  New England       8½ev
```

Also I tried to write them down to a csv file and I get this error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

and here is the code I am using:

```
from pandas as pd

url = 'http://exoweb0.donbest.com/checkHTML/servlet/send_archive_history.servlet?by_casino=1&for_casino=37&league=1&game=0&date=20151029'
data = pd.read_html(url, header=0)      
data.to_csv('Pinacle Lines.csv', index_col=0)
#print (data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
data = pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]
```

You get a list of DataFrame's back when you call read_html, you need to figure out which one you want, the edit above will select the first one, you might want to look at all of them.